# Function the_custom_logo() in PHP forcing two image tags when i inspect element

Tags: php, wordpress, image, function, header

I am working on a web page and I almost finished, but my logo doesn`t work.
I need to do it via function the_custom_logo(). After I do that 2 image tags appear when I go to inspect element. I will post your picture and code.

After publishing logo in customize options in WordPress all I need is to call that custom logo function. But as you can see I have a big issue.

```
<a class="country-logo" href="<?php  echo site_url() ?>">
 <img class="country-logo-style" src="<?php the_custom_logo(); ?>" alt="Pro Denver Movers Logo" >
</a>
```

I just need this Denver logo to fit without second image showing.

I have a link to the webpage

http://prodenvermovers.wpupkeep.org/

You can check and inspect element here on webpage and see what is the actual problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Problem here: ``src="<a href="``

Comment: ``<img class="country-logo-style lazyloading" src="<a href=" http:="" prodenvermovers.wpupkeep.org="" "="" rel="home" data-was-processed="true">`` What syntax is that ? looks like having a lot of issues.

Comment: I dont get it what i need to change in code ?

Comment: I rly dont know man what syntax is that. I just used the_custom_logo function and before that i put logo inside of customize in wordpress. thats all

Comment: Can you share ``the_custom_logo()`` function source here please. The issue persist, the code doesn't show an image and HTML has a bad syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`the_custom_logo` will automatically echo the right HTML code to display the logo.

Try this one.

```
<a class="country-logo" href="<?php  echo site_url() ?>">
    <?php the_custom_logo(); ?>
</a>
```

Comment: Glad to help you. If it's working as expected please mark this ans :)

Comment: I don't see the image, i changed browser and see same thing. Some text bottom of image: ``" alt="Pro Denver Movers Logo" >``

Comment: you dont need img and src of custom logo function...Custom logo function defines HTML img tag by default. I didnt knew that :)

Comment: yes, you can check that function in  wordpress core file general-template.php. https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.2/src/wp-includes/general-template.php#L1014